# How to migrate data between datastores using Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

Is it possible to migrate data between two different datastores using [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)?

I'm currently storing images in the DB - using a custom relational data store, and want to migrate to an S3-like web API sore.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in issue [markevans/dragonfly
 #382](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/issues/382#issuecomment-98373673) on github.

In short:

- update Dragonfly configuration to new sorage
- keep old storoage configuration in "named" config
- you can access attachemnts from old storage by:

```
job = Dragonfly.app("filestore").fetch(model.attachment_uid)
model.attachment = job.to_file(job.name)
```

Another solution worth mentioning I found here https://gist.github.com/lassebunk/cce8b54d7d36da0960eb)

(@CambridgeMike it is probably your own issue, but recording answers for others here).